# How can I rename the submit button to kendoForm

Tags: kendo-ui

in kendoForm i can't find the submit button to rename from submit in save.

SampleCode: https://dojo.telerik.com/EkEXENEL

kendo.ui.Form API Reference: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `buttonsTemplate`

```
 $("#exampleform").kendoForm({
     orientation: "vertical",
     buttonsTemplate: '<button class="k-button k-primary k-form-submit" type="submit">Save</button><button class="k-button k-form-clear">Clear</button>'
...
```

Example: [buttonsTemplate](https://dojo.telerik.com/OdURAhiv)

Documentation: [buttonsTemplate](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/form/configuration/buttonstemplate)